# Ever more is never enough

Tags: cipher, alphametic

A certain USA celebrity tweeted a cryptarithm,
which includes a cipher with an encrypted clue,
for friends in a nearby country.

$$
\begin{array}{r} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad~~
\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]
\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]
\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]
\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]
\tt      E \, V \, E \, R  ~\\[-1ex]
\tt  +\, M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[.5ex]
\hline \end{array}
\\
13.15 - \frac{18}{19.5} + 0.0 + \cdots + \frac3{15} - \frac45 + \cdots
$$

What did he or she want and how much?

**Post-solution note**

The core encryption idea here is from @question_asker,
who let me run with it and promised not to solve this.
Anyone seen this system used before?

Comment: Is there an answer that doesn't include fractions?

Comment: No actual fractions involved, @Daedric, just looks like it

Comment: uhh. I'm kinda new to these, but how am I supposed to figure out the answer with all the "..."s in the math solution. Wouldn't that affect the puzzle in some way?

Comment: Good for zeroing in on the "..."s, @Nyk232, which are crucial but made to look like something different than what they really mean.

Comment: hmm...well, they just look like empty **space** to me, but there's no way that's true.

Comment: Right, @Nyk232, there are two kinds of spaces in the cryptogram that are disguised in their own ways to different extents

Comment: @Pangloss Sorry for editing hastily and making assumptions.  Since you mentioned that the cryptarithm already contains a "cipher with an encrypted clue," I assumed that meant that it needed to be *de*ciphered.  May I suggest the more common "**enciphered**" rather than "**ciphered**" to make your intention more clear?

Comment: @Pangloss Perhaps my other edit was made in haste as well, and ought to be reverted?

Comment: uhhmm. are the decimal places supposed to be letters, too, or are they just for show?

Comment: @Nyk232, the way you're gong now you might not even need the encrypted clue

Comment: No problem with the MathJaX edit, @GentlePurpleRain, thank you. Thanks also for helping me realize that "ciphered," now gone altogether, was just trying to be a cutesy borrow of its meaning in the Beverly Hillbillies TV show.

Comment: Surprisingly good, @Nyk232. You're well on the way to figuring out what is meant to be the least straightforward part this puzzle, especially without the encrypted clue, which itself is meant to be straightforward enough to pass under the radar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She wants

> **17,909 (Mexican) pesos**

If you consider each of the numbers below the horizontal line as a letter (A=1, B=2, etc.), you get

> $M.O - \frac{R}{S.E} + 0.0 + \cdots + \frac{C}{O} - \frac{D}{E} + \cdots$
>  (**MORSE CODE**)

Taking that as a clue, and looking at the dots and dashes on that line (decimal points, ellipses, minus signs, fraction dividers), you get

> $\cdot - - \cdot \quad \cdot \quad \cdots \quad - - - \quad \cdots$
>  $\quad P \quad \quad E \quad S \quad \quad \;\; O \quad \quad \; \; S$

This gives you the alphametic

> $$\begin{array}{r} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad~~\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      E \, V \, E \, R  ~\\[-1ex]\tt  +\, M \, O \, R \, E  ~\\[.5ex]\hline\tt    P\, E \, S \, O \, S  ~\\[-1ex] \end{array}\\$$

which can be solved as

> $$\begin{array}{r} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad~~\tt      2 \, 0 \, 4 \, 7  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      2 \, 0 \, 4 \, 7  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      2 \, 0 \, 4 \, 7  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      2 \, 0 \, 4 \, 7  ~\\[-1ex]\tt      7 \, 6 \, 7 \, 4  ~\\[-1ex]\tt  +\, 2 \, 0 \, 4 \, 7  ~\\[.5ex]\hline\tt    1\, 7 \, 9 \, 0 \, 9  ~\\[-1ex] \end{array}\\$$

Comment: this makes the most sense to me based on the OP's clues in the comments. I was stuck on how to use the mathematical signs, but I guess they were just there for show...

Comment: wait...you say A=1, B=2, ..., but then in the equation, you substitute 7 for E, not 5. Why is that?

Comment: @Nyk232  A=1, B=2 only applies to decrypting the hint (the stuff below the horizontal line).  After I've determined the alphametic (fourth spoiler block), I solve that to determine a value for each of the letters.

Comment: alright, I think I get how these things work now.

Comment: Omg, I thought of morse but didn't capitalize on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think she wants

> Forever more

Because

> There are 4 mores, making "for" as it sounds like "four". Then just finish the statement.

Comment: Love it. Even makes sense with this puzzle's title and is good idea for another puzzle! This one, though, has more more in a different vein.

Comment: you read 'forever more' and i read 'for more ever more'.. :p

Comment: @manshu well. I read **four**ever more :P

Answer (score 2):

This is just a partial answer, of course, but I think it's actually

> something that's forever.

If you look at the words, you can see that you get

> "four more" and "ever more"

which can be combined to form

> "former" and "evermore"

Now, if we take a look at the last 2 numbers in the sequence, we see that

> One has a **3** divided by **(5*3)**, and the other has **4/5**.

Since we have two words, and "more is common enough", lets

> substitute "more" for 5, and then apply the fractions to the words from earlier. If you subtract the **last** **three** letters from "former", you get **"for"**. IF you do the same with the **last** **four** letters from "evermore", you get "ever."

Now, in most games like battleship, two letters joined with a dash reference a row and column, and can be combined together.

> Thus, we end up with the word **"forever"**, and the fact that "MORE" and 5 are somehow related.

Comment: Just tell me if I'm on the other side of the coast with this one. I doubt I'm in the ballpark anymore.

Comment: Very creative and another(!) idea for a good puzzle. I don't have a chance at the moment to fully appreciate this answer beyond seeing that it goes in a direction that will probably miss 2/3 of this puzzle.

Comment: Well, 1/3rd is a lot better than I thought, so I'll take what little winnings I have and bid out now. :)